# iOS - Use Tabs as a Filter

Tags: ios, tabs, uitabbarcontroller

Is it possible to use tabs to act as a filter for a list view?

I know you can add new tabs by hooking them up to new view controllers, but I would ideally like to use the same view controller, but show different items based on which tab is selected.

Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may want to use a `UISegmentedControl` instead. It looks kinda like a tabbar and of course you can use it to filter list results.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html

Answer (score 1):

I would not suggest using tab for that purpose.If the filtered results are to be shown in the same view controller you can use Segmented Control with various segments.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SegmentedControl/Articles/SegmentedControlCode.html